# Аутентификация и авторизация ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте!

Я создаю сайт с использованием ASP.NET MVC 3. В данный момент дошел до реализации прав доступа админа сайта. Во многих руководствах и примерах, которые я смотрел, используется готовое встроенное решение на основе Web Site Administration Tool, где используются свои сгенерированные таблицы. Мне бы хотелось создать собственную логику права доступа для админа со своей базой данных. Для этого мне необходимо создать класс модели данных и контроллер, который будет управлять этой моделью. Кто-нибудь может помочь с данным вопросом?

Comment: Буду следить за темой, тоже интересно.

Comment: Мне вот на MSDN форуме посоветовали следующее:
"Отнаследуй и задави asp.net membership и напиши свою реализацию,
можешь покопатся в сырцах http://mytripmvc.codeplex.com/ - тут как раз на мвс3 все сделали. А вообще, это не привязано конкретно к мвс, все просто отнаследовал и задавил. ))"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делал свою реализацию на основе тутора.
Вот почитайте перевод [Custom membership provider](http://shiftnotes.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/custom-membership-provider-part-1/).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 7):

Речь идет про Windows Forms Authorization.

Если коротко, то вам нужно имплементировать свои классы, унаследованные от абстрактных **MembershipProvider** и **RoleProvider**, отвечающих в данной модели авторизации за пользователей и роли соответственно.

В созданных классах перекрываете только нужные методы и свойства.

Перекрытие методов как раз и позволит использовать свою структуру базы данных.

Созданные провайдеры нужно указать в конфиге сайта в разделах **membership** и **roleManager** по примеру уже существующих там записей.

Так же можно кастомизировать **ProfileProvider** для работы с профилями пользователей.

Простой пример имплементации **MembershipProvider**:

```
public class SiteMember
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider {

    private static List<SiteMember> Members = new List<SiteMember> {
        new SiteMember { UserName = "MyUser", Password = "MyPass" }
    };

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password) {
        return Members.Exists(m => (m.UserName==username)&&(m.Password==password));
    }
}
```